# How can I remove Description Label in ios-chart?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

I am trying to remove `Description Label` in `ios-chart` library. You can see it on the image below:

[image]

And I know that, on Android (`MPAndroidChart` library which is the predecessor of ios-chart), I can do the following:

```
barchart.setDescription(" ");
```

but I am trying to do the same on Swift:

```
barchart.description = ""
```

and I am getting the following error:

> Cannot assign to property: 'description' is immutable

I have looked on the Internet and here in StackOverflow but could not see anything to remove it.

Is it possible to remove that `Description Label` on `ios-chart` library?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 50, accepted):

It's `descriptionText`, not `description`, `description` is `NSObject` variable

On **Swift 3.0 and Chart 3.0**:

```
barchart.chartDescription?.text = ""
```

Comment: Thank you very much! In `Swift 3.0` I could see that it is deprecated so you should use `barchart.chartDescription?.text = ""`. I will accept the answer as fast I could. +1 by the moment :D

Comment: thanks for the edit :D i was still using swift 2 version so it's that one

Answer (score 14):

It could work better in **Swift 3.0** by disabling as

```
   barChart.chartDescription?.enabled = false
```

Comment: You can also remove it altogether as
barChart.chartDescription = nil as its an _optional_ value

Answer (score 0):

In new version description is not a String its ChartDescription class.

```
ChartDescription *desc = [[ChartDescription alloc]init];
desc.text = @"";
chart.chartDescription = desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

For swift 4

`barChart.chartDescription?.text = ""`